# Failed to install MStest plugin : Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli, jenkins-scriptler

I try to install the  MSTest for showing the results from .trx file.

As I install through Download Now and Install after Restart, My Jenkins is taking so long time to restart so I tried with Install without restart.

It shows the following error

```
enter code here

Emma plugin 
      Failure -

java.io.IOException: Failed to dynamically deploy this plugin
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1317)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1116)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:104)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to install emma plugin
    at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:473)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1313)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Dependency maven-plugin (1.447) doesn't exist
    at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:480)
    at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:463)
    ... 6 more

MSTest plugin   Failure -

java.io.IOException: Failed to dynamically deploy this plugin
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1317)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1116)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:104)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to install mstest plugin
    at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:473)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1313)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Dependency emma (1.29) doesn't exist
    at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:480)
    at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:463)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: `Dependency maven-plugin (1.447) doesn't exist`. Do you have the maven plugin?

Comment: Most probably a problem with your Network.
I uploaded the two plugins to here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/oru5cdb59yjq0ll/AAAfpe5BL3nf_eVd48MHCTA4a?dl=0

Comment: maven-plugin was not installed and it was not showing in the dependency plugins also. Only Emma was shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because MSTest plugin depends on emma and maven-plugin. I suspect you have bad network condition while download these 2 dependencies.
First, try `Download Now and Install after Restart` but wait for a longer time until it get successfully installed. Jenkins will take care of the dependencies.

Or,
as an alternative, you can first install emma and maven-plugin, then install MSTest then.